# Configuring pipeline options in Apache Beam - Touring example fails

Tags: beam

https://tour.beam.apache.org/tour/java/introduction/beam-concepts/pipeline-concepts/setting-pipeline

the only difference in my code is the location of the input and output file.. I have kept it under src/main/resources/my-bucket/sample1000.csv. I gave the absolute path as well -

@Default.String("/Users/myname/IdeaProjects/myproject/src/main/resources/my-bucket/sample1000.csv")

From the LOGGER console output I can directly navigate to the input csv file link. it should work. But, I am not seeing any output.

Need help

Expecting the output per https://tour.beam.apache.org/tour/java/introduction/beam-concepts/pipeline-concepts/setting-pipeline

Comment: 1/2..
I have tried both Java 17 and 21. I get this error stack:

===============

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':DataWatcher.main()'.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149)
 at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
 at 
....

Comment: 2/2

....
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
 at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:431)
..

Comment: I think, it errors out in the visit pattern, nested. So, it is essentially reading and failing somewhere in the pipeline.. Someone who wrote the tour please help me so that I don't waste my time on some bad data. Still, I it should error out more gracefully, and with clear indicator of the exception point.

Comment: Here is the link to the error / debug view

https://ibb.co/9wWm4Vv

Comment: Hey SRK, please add all this additional information to your question by editing instead of using comments.